# Comparing `system-configuration-options` to a user-specified list

Tags: list

In this example, the `system-configuration-options` is a string:

`"--prefix=/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.x11 --with-x --with-ns=no --enable-checking=yes,glyphs --enable-check-lisp-object-type --without-compress-install 'CFLAGS=-O0 -g3' CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/include LDFLAGS=-L/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/lib"`

Inasmuch as the order of the configuration options may change, I would like to come up with a fancier test than the layman's approach (i.e, me) using `split-string` and comparing each element one-by-one with `member` using `mapc`.  [Some `cl-...` magic, for example, would be nifty.]

MY CUSTOM LIST:

```
'("--prefix=/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.x11"
  "--with-x"
  "--with-ns=no"
  "--enable-checking=yes,glyphs"
  "--enable-check-lisp-object-type"
  "--without-compress-install"
  "'CFLAGS=-O0 -g3'"
  "CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/include"
  "LDFLAGS=-L/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/lib")
```

**Q**:  How to programmatically determine whether `system-configuration-options` contains ALL of the members of My Custom List?

Comment: Why not split these strings the way you suggested, sort lists, and then put them in two buffers and `ediff-buffer`?

Comment: @wvxvw -- Thank you for taking a look at this thread.  I was thinking that there is probably some `cl-...-thing-a-majig` combination that can do this in a few lines of code.  I haven't used `ediff-buffer`, but would be pleased to research that possibility with a cup of coffee in the morning ...

Answer (score 1):

Do mind that you may have to do some extra work since the `''` got parsed out by the shell

```
(require 's)
(require 'dash)
(let* ((my-list '("--prefix=/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.x11"
                  "--with-x"
                  "--with-ns=no"
                  "--enable-checking=yes,glyphs"
                  "--enable-check-lisp-object-type"
                  "--without-compress-install"
                  "'CFLAGS=-O0 -g3'"
                  "CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/include"
                  "LDFLAGS=-L/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/lib"))
       (_s "--prefix=/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.x11 --with-x --with-ns=no --enable-checking=yes,glyphs --enable-check-lisp-object-type --without-compress-install 'CFLAGS=-O0 -g3' CPPFLA↩
GS=-I/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/include LDFLAGS=-L/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.macports/lib")
       (separator "\n")
       (shell-separated (shell-command-to-string (format "printf '%%s%s' %s"
                                                    separator
                                                    _s)))
       (as-list (s-split separator shell-separated t))
       (diff (-difference as-list my-list)))
  diff
  )
;; prints ("CFLAGS=-O0 -g3")
```